# Не правильно считается сумма на си для uint64_t

Tags: c

есть условный си код:

```
uin64_t a,b;
a = a + b;
```

если  подать в него -  `a = 8c011084677d67f2` и `b = 7cbeb64a7dde6e22`

результат будет на СИ `08c0c6cee45bd614`

калькулятор дает результат `108BFC6CEE55BD614`

ПЛИС дает результат `08bfc6cee55bd614`

но это половина беды, если подать:

```
a = 6cdcb11489b21a61
b = 635d17bdcd755d4e
```

то результат будет:

Си: `cf39c9d1562878af`

Калькулятор: `D039C8D2572777AF`

ПЛИС: `d039c8d2572777af`

На си поведение устойчивое - те на разных компиляторах результат одинаковый или близкий к одинаковому

**Объясните, плизз, почему так и как считать правильно..... +)**

UPD: Добавил код, проверил еще раз:

Си  = `788f156dbbc97800`
 ПЛИС = `788f156dbbc87900`
 Калькулятор = `788F156DBBC87900`

```
static inline uint64_t rotr64( const uint64_t w, const unsigned c ){
    return ( w >> c ) | ( w << ( 64 - c ) );
}

/*Blake's G function*/
#define G(r,i,a,b,c,d) \
  do { \
    a = a + b; \
    d = rotr64(d ^ a, 32); \
    c = c + d; \
    b = rotr64(b ^ c, 24); \
    a = a + b; \
    d = rotr64(d ^ a, 16); \
    c = c + d; \
    b = rotr64(b ^ c, 63); \
  } while(0)


/*One Round of the Blake's 2 compression function*/
#define ROUND_LYRA(r)  \
    G(r,0,v[ 0],v[ 4],v[ 8],v[12]); \
    G(r,1,v[ 1],v[ 5],v[ 9],v[13]); \
    G(r,2,v[ 2],v[ 6],v[10],v[14]); \
    G(r,3,v[ 3],v[ 7],v[11],v[15]); \
    G(r,4,v[ 0],v[ 5],v[10],v[15]); \
    G(r,5,v[ 1],v[ 6],v[11],v[12]); \
    G(r,6,v[ 2],v[ 7],v[ 8],v[13]); \
    G(r,7,v[ 3],v[ 4],v[ 9],v[14]);


inline static void reducedBlake2bLyra(uint64_t *v) {
    ROUND_LYRA(0);
}


int main()
{
uint64_t *state = malloc(16 * sizeof (uint64_t));

 state[0]  = 0x886405bc4ef729f4;
 state[1]  = 0xeef412028f17fe52;
 state[2]  = 0xc14af5d9d8c1b0d6;
 state[3]  = 0xb4bf0fb0007f7cd8;
 state[4]  = 0x7814c3ff1e1e6584;
 state[5]  = 0x0198a05583c8a31a;
 state[6]  = 0x495a3b6304587341;
 state[7]  = 0x6489e4d1e286df36;
 state[8]  = 0x42c008c5e5f0b5b8;
 state[9]  = 0x81473c472e5c1272;
 state[10] = 0x6ee801e3f691cc77;
 state[11] = 0x3c4a0a05167955f4;
 state[12] = 0x8310219b03708b66;
 state[13] = 0x6bb0801460ab97ea;
 state[14] = 0x13272757d8f7e5fe;
 state[15] = 0x3524a4286f596d06;
    reducedBlake2bLyra(state);

    return 0;
}
```

UPD2: что бы Добить

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2838316d049a2c13 - **788f156dbbc97800**

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92024213ca202525 - **788f156dbbc87900**

Comment: Результат не влезает в 64-битный int (хотя во втором случае таки влезает, тогда да, нужен код)

Comment: Покажите ваш код на С для второго случая. У меня второй ответ [совпадает с калькулятором](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3ec715ab93b6687).

Comment: Что такое "правильно"? В языке С беззнаковые типы реализуют арифметику по модулю. И для арифметики по модулю результат у вас получился совершенно правильный, в первом случае. А вот как вам удалось получить такой результат во втором случае - это уже у вас надо спрашивать.

Comment: AnT - просьба внимательнее посмотреть на числа:
108bfc6cee55bd614 - калькулятор
  08bfc6cee55bd614 - плис
  08c0c6cee45bd614 -си

Comment: Я выше ссылку привел, где у меня на С все правильно считается (но с переполнением в первом случае). Попробуйте его у себя запустить и скажите, какой будет результат. А то в вашем коде куча какой-то непонятной математики, и неясно, что мы должны в нем увидеть.

Comment: У вас си на какой машине (и в какой ОС)? У меня в `gcc.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609; Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz` результат (для сложения 8c011084677d67f2 с 7cbeb64a7dde6e22 и 6cdcb11489b21a61 с 635d17bdcd755d4e) в обоих случаях тот же, что у вас на ПЛИС

Comment: привел код Для  обоих вариантов ответа на http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com - что бы исключить разность см. UPD2

проблема в том что то ПО которое "надо" компилируется везде именно по варианту "788f156dbbc97800", а 4 РАЗНЫХ варианта сумматоров на ПЛИС все дают "788f156dbbc87900"

Comment: Ничего не понял. Что вы пытаетесь продемонстрировать своими примерами на coliru? Первая ссылка вычисляет сумму `886405bc4ef729f4 + 7814c3ff1e1e6584`, которая равна `0078c9bb6d158f78`, и после этого печатает ее задом наперед: от младших байтов к старшим. Получается `788f156dbbc97800`. Вторая ссылка вычисляет сумму `f429f74ebc056488 + 84651e1effc31478`, которая равна `788f156dbbc87900` и печатает ее нормальным образом. Если бы при суммировании не возникало переноса из байта в байт, то можно было бы ожидать одинакового результата от таких "зеркальных" сложений. Но у вас-то ведь перенос возникает!

Comment: "Но у вас-то ведь перенос возникает! " - вот именно это я и пытаюсь понять - почему, где и как это повторить там Где не возникает переноса - тк Ситуация с 788f156dbbc97800 - "правильная" с ТЗ исходного ПО

Comment: Не понимаю вопроса. Если при сложении возникает перенос из байта в байт, то два "зеркальных" сложения будут давать *разные* наборы байтов в результатах, т.к. перенос всегда движется справа налево. Если же при сложении переноса из байта в байт не возникает, то наборы байтов в результатах будут одинаковыми ("зеркальными"). Все. У вас перенос возник - наборы получились разные, как и должно быть.

Comment: Откуда  возникает перенос? - вот главный вопрос - тк он "прописан" в Исходном ПО - мне нужно Понять механику переноса  для имплементации на ПЛИС